# Perl - variable as hash key

Tags: perl, hash

1. I'm returning a hash from the subroutine

   ```
   my %hash = %{subroutine()};
   ```
2. later on I want to use the hash element as follows

   ```
   if (defined $hash{LEVEL_1_KEY}{LEVEL_2_KEY}){
   .
   .
   .}
   ```

This works well. 
But If I want to try to use same element with LEVEL_1_KEY coming from variable. It doesn't work.
e.g.

```
my $var = "LEVEL_1_KEY";
if (defined $hash{$var}{LEVEL_2_KEY}){
...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use some apostrophes, or quotes with $var? I tried several things, but no success yet.

Comment: Question what is %hash content => `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash`

Comment: Is the value really defined? Don't you need `exists` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't work"*? What behaviour are you seeing? Apart from a missing closing brace, which I assume is a typing mistake, there is nothing wrong with what you have written. Is the assignment of `$var` more complicated than that? For instance, is it read from a file, or is it built from the value of another variable?

Comment: as said by @choroba you should use 'exists'. also you should check in two steps: if( exists $hash{$var} and exists $hash{$var}{LEVEL_2_KEY} ){ ... }

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: Please don't keep making trivial changes to the question.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my explanation. The point is if I'm using string "LEVEL_1_KEY" to access hash element, than it works, but If I insert same string into $var and then want to use the hash element, it doesn't work, hash element can't be found/printed etc

Comment: @Borodin: I corrected the grammar, is that not allowed?

Comment: @taiko: That isn't possible. The contents of `$var` aren't what you think. Use `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $var;` to find out exactly what is in there.

Comment: @taiko would you put money on that?

Comment: @Borodin: OK. I'll take care from next time.

Comment: `exists $hash{key}` and `defined $hash{key}` are *not* interchangeable.  Both have valid uses on a hash.  Use `defined` if you want to check if the value stored in the hash is defined.  Use `exists` if you want to check the hash slot exists, even if the value is undefined.  Usually you want to use `defined`, a well used hash can fill up with all sorts of empty slots.

Comment: @Pierre Unless you're concerned about forcing the first level to spring into existence, there's no need to check for multi-level hash key existence in two steps.  If you are concerned about that, use [`no autovivification`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification).  This is another reason to favor `defined` over `exists`.

Comment: @Schwern +1 It seems I got things messed up :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should work as written, so there's something left out of your code.

My first impulse is the use of `defined`.  Checking with `exists` or `defined` is a red flag.  It means your code is using trinary or even quadrary logic.  True, false, defined and existence.  Worse, they overlap: true is also defined; undefined is also false; existence combines with any of the others; and so on.  There are valid uses for checking if a thing is `defined`, but casual use is confusing and error prone.  It's very easy for a false value to sneak into a slot that's supposed to remain undefined.  Consider changing the defined check to a truth check.

(The primary use of `defined` would be where 0 or `''` is a valid value).

Here's general debugging ideas.

- Does `$var` contain what you think it contains?

Print it out just before it is used.

- Does `$var` *really* contain what you think it contains?

Print it out *with quotes* like `print qq['$var']` to catch any trailing whitespace.

- Does `$var` *really* *really* contain what you think it contains?

Is it coming from a filehandle?  Could it contain special Unicode that looks like plain ASCII?  Try `print "Yes" if $var eq "LEVEL_1_KEY"`

- Are you sure you don't have single quotes around `$var`?

It's `$hash{$var}` right?  Not `$hash{'$var'}`.

- Does `%hash` contain what you think it contains?

Dump it out using Data::Dumper just before you use it.

- Is that line of code even reached?

Print a print statement before the condition.

- Does the condition block do anything?

Maybe the condition is working, but the code inside the block doesn't.  Put a print statement *inside* the block just after the condition.

- Just because it's defined doesn't mean it's true.

You're checking the value is defined, not true.  It could be an empty string.  It could be all spaces.  It could be 0.  Does the rest of the code want a defined value or a true value?

As a side note, you're somewhat better off leaving the return value from your subroutine as a hash reference, rather than dereferencing it.  Dereferencing causes a temporary copy of the hash to be made which can use CPU and memory.  How much impact this will really have depends on how big the hash is, and you should get used to working with references for general efficiency.

Comment: +1 Thanx for taking the time to try to teach how to debug.  Teaching someone to fish has got to be at least 10 times harder than just giving him a fish, but I think you did a good job of communicating the debugging steps that are so innate to most of us that they're actually hard to describe.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code

```
if (defined $hash{LEVEL_1_KEY}{LEVEL_2_KEY){
```

should be

```
if (defined $hash{LEVEL_1_KEY}{LEVEL_2_KEY}){
```

---

Rest it works fine, you can check it here: http://ideone.com/QT36e4

Are you sure you are writing $var like you stated or are you taking the name from some file or STDIN?

Comment: The first example, which *"works well"*, has the same syntax error. Presumably that isn't the problem.

Comment: yeah it was a typo only

Comment: Typos mean that you aren't cutting and pasting the actual code that you want help with. That's a really bad idea.